# Node.JS with Express and SASS - Compiled CSS file not applied

Tags: css, node.js, express, sass, pug

I'm new to NodeJS and I'm using Express to serve my pug files/view. Furthermore I'm using "express-sass-middleware" to compile and serve the scss/css files. Everything works very well but unfortunately, the CSS are not applied.

My app.js files looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var sassMiddleware = require('express-sass-middleware');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/css/bootstrap.css', sassMiddleware({
  file: 'css/bootstrap.scss', // the location of the entry point,
                                     // this can also be a directory

  precompile: true,                   // should it be compiled on server start
                                     // or deferred to the first request
                                     //  - defaults to false
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        varTitle: 'Hello World'
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

And my simple css file looks like:

```
// $icon-font-path: /3rdparty/fonts;

// @import 'bootstrap/bootstrap';
// @import './node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables';

body
{
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

My index.pug file is:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title= varTitle
    link(ref='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/bootstrap.css')
  body
    h1= varTitle
```

Now, when I start my webserver using "node app.js", accessing http://localhost:3000, I see "Hello World" but unfortunately the body background isn't green and the text is also not 100px. That means that the css file is not applied. But when I access http://localhost:3000/css/bootstrap.css, I see the valid, css file.

Anyone know what I'm missing here? I'm a bit confused that I see the CSS source when accessing it directly but the browser doesn't apply the css styling. I already tried different browsers without any success. None of them applying the css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typing error in `index.pug` file for loading `css` file. You had mentioned `ref` whereas it should be `rel`.

```
link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/bootstrap.css')
```

Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you don't seem to be serving the static files from your nodejs server code. You have to add your css dir in order to allow access from your html code:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory from the /static path prefix.

```
http://localhost:3000/static/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/static/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/static/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/static/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/static/hello.html
```